# How to remove/hide the X-axis number in achartengine of Android?

Tags: android

I use achartengine to draw some statistics bar graph on my Android application. [image: achartengine app]

As you can see from the above picture, the X(Y)-axis contains a series of number: 10 20 30 40 ... And I want to remove/hide the X-axis numbers. Does anyone know how to do it via programming? Or in another word, how to change achartengine's settings to achieve it. Thanks!

**I find the answer:**

```
// by it, the x-axis number 0 10 20 30.. can be hiden
renderer.setXLabels(RESULT_OK);
```

Comment: Hi your solution is useful but I find that RESULT_OK is defined in Android system, which is -1. If someday Android change the definition of RESULT_OK you might have to modify the code. Maybe the better answer you can use -1 or 0 instead of RESULT_OK.

Comment: RESULT_OK is just a constant defined by android system. What @GarlicTseng said is absolutely right.

Answer (score 10):

Hey you can use method

```
renderer.setXLabels(0);
```

This method accept maximum number of label that should be displayed on X axis.

Answer (score 0):

well, upon testing it's not working for me but this seems like the way to do it. perhaps it might work for you:

```
mrenderer.clearXTextLabels();
```

where `mrenderer` is the `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer()`

if you wanna do your own digging, here's a [site](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/index.html) that shows some much less than ubiquitous documentation on the library.

Comment: Thank you! Please check my main post, I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
renderer.setXLabels(0);
renderer.setYLabels(12); 
renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "a");
renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "b");
renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "c");
renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "d");
renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "e");
renderer.addXTextLabel(6, "f");
```

Comment: Could you add a small explanation?